# How to do ctrl+f in webdriver/java, just like F5

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to do ctrl+f in webdriver/java? I have to do in a way where there are 2 excel sheets, each excel sheet contains list of email addresses. So need to copy each cell email, and search it in a web page. If it finds that email address in the web page then copy the corresponding data and save it in another excel sheet.

I know how to do ctrl+f5 using web driver, but ctrl+f is littly tricky. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you try this method `keyDown(Keys.getKeyFromUnicode('f'))` let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `Keys.chord()` method:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("your-xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "f"));
```

or by using the `Action` class and the unicode representation:

```
Actions action = new Actions(); 
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0066')).perform();
```

For a full list of unicode characters read more [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).

Comment: hi just now in, will try it and let you know

Comment: hi, in this driver.findElement(By.xPath("your-xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "f")); which element xpath should I insert?

Comment: Since you're searching on a web page, you could add the `html` tag. However, It would be best if you'd use the `Action` class in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(driver.findElement(By.XPath("//tagname[text()='mailID']")).isDisplayed){
// write your code
}
```

or

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.XPath("//tagname[text()='mailID']")).isEmpty){
// write your code
}
```

Comment: Do I need to edit "//tagname[text()='mailID']" in my xpath?

Comment: Yes, replace 'tagname' string with the tag of the element where you are searching and 'mailID' is what string you are searching for